# How do I check if the user input is strictly numbers, using the bool type?

Tags: c#, string, validation, integer, boolean

I defined a string data type. Prompted the user to enter 10 numbers. e.g Console.Write("Enter your cell number: ");
I want to know how to validate the string and make sure the user entered numbers only

Comment: How do you as a human decide if something scrawled on a postit is words or numbers?  Get the computer to do the same

Comment: Hint: this is a good place to use regular expressions. But we're not just going to solve the problem for you: you should show what attempt you've made, and what happened.

Comment: Try parsing the string....

Comment: @un-lucky here is my code for the method im working on. It's not much, I'm completely stuck static bool ValidCharacters(string cellNumber)
        {
            int value;
            bool valid = true;
            value =
        }

Comment: You have to define _number_ first. You want to allow any number(like `123456.789`) or only integers? Is this also allowed: `1234567898765432123456789`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter numbers with no decimals, with a max of ten. eg 1234567890

Comment: max length of 10, min length of 1, only digits: `@"^[\d]{1,10}$"`

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be use regular expression to much exactly 10 digits:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^\d{10}$");

if(pattern.isMatch(input))
{
    //Do something
    return true;
}
```

Another option is to use `Int64.TryParse`, read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx), but that additional checks are needed, to verify that result had 10 digits (no more, no less), number is not negative etc.

```
 bool result = Int64.TryParse(value, out number);
 if (result)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);             
 }
```

Comment: `int.TryParse` will also allow negative numbers...

Comment: But it won't allow 9999999999...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, how about Int64.TryParse ? If it is not enough - then regex.

Comment: @Zohar Peled, additional check  (>0) would solve that.

Comment: That would still allow negative numbers - and fewer than or more than 10 digits. If the aim is to check whether a string contains exactly 10 digits, I think a regular expression is the best option.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, you're right, fixed.

Comment: Is there any reason it's more complicated than `@"^\d{10}$"`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, in this case no, you're right again. It would only help if you will need to find 10 digits number in longer string. I will change answer.